# Como eu escrevo essa fórmula em .formula?

Tags: vba

Como eu escrevo a fórmula abaixo em .formula no vba?

`=SE(J5="OK";"Realizado";SE(E(J5="NOK";I5>0);"Não realizado";SE( E(J5="NOK";I5<0); "Não realizado")`

Comment: par ao condicional `se` use `Range`: `If Range(“J5”) = "OK" Then .....`

Answer (score 0):

A utilização dessa formula em `.formula` implica ajustar o estilo para o inglês, o que significa:

- Trocar `;` por `,`
- Trocar os nomes das funções para o inglês. Ex: `SE` passa a `IF`
- Escapar todas as aspas duplas dentro da formula colocando duas seguidas

No exemplo que tem ficaria assim:

```
ActiveCell.formula = "=IF(J5=""OK"",""Realizado"",IF(AND(J5=""NOK"",I5>0),""Não realizado"",IF(AND(J5=""NOK"",I5<0),""Não realizado"")))"
```

Coloquei como célula de destino a a célula corrente com `ActiveCell`, mas pode ajustar para a que der jeito, com o `Range`.

Pessoalmente acho que fica mais simples utilizar código VBA normal, como se tratasse de programação normal, e fazer assim:

```
If Range("J5").Value = "OK" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Realizado"
ElseIf Range("J5").Value = "NOK" And Range("I5").Value > 0 Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Não Realizado"
ElseIf Range("J6").Value = "NOK" And Range("I5").Value < 0 Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Não Realizado"
End If
```

Apesar de tudo isto não é uma formula e por isso não se vai ajustar com base nas alterações dos restantes valores, e por isso pode não servir para o seu objetivo.

Agora se reparar, tem duas atribuições iguais nos `ElseIf`, o que faz com que não faça muito sentido essa construção e é algo que tem de rever.

Para o que está escrito, basta colocar `"Realizado"` quando `J5` tem o valor `"Ok"` e `"Não Realizado"` quando `J5` tem `"NOK"` que representa o mesmo. Para tal basta o seguinte:

```
If Range("J5").Value = "OK" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Realizado"
ElseIf Range("J5").Value = "NOK" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Não Realizado"
End If
```

No exemplo do `.formula` o mesmo principio se aplica, e a mesma simplificação nesse caso seria:

```
ActiveCell.formula = "=IF(J5=""OK"",""Realizado"",IF(AND(J5=""NOK""),""Não realizado""))"
```